# Why I can't Raw element inside function block?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Here is my code:

```
@{
  string RawString="";
  //some switch logic to set RawString;
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RawString))
    {
        Html.Raw(RawString);
    }
}
```

However, in spite `Html.Raw(RawString)` works without any error. It never renders in HTML.

What's wrong with my code? Thank you.

Comment: you need to wrap `<text></text>` around your `@Html.Raw` (note about that `@` used then).

Comment: @KingKing Whereas, the RawString is not only one type element, it may be a <link> or a <script>.

Comment: if you have any other html element around it, just use that instead of `<text></text>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> @{
>   string RawString="";
>   //some switch logic to set RawString;
>   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RawString))
>     {
>         Html.Raw(RawString);
>     }
> }
> ```

Perhaps the issue is related the `Html.Raw()` method, you are missing an `@` symbol before the `Html.Raw()` method.

Check the following sample code:

```
@{
    string RawString = "<style>#div_content{ background-color:green;} </style><div id='div_content'>AAA</div>";
    //some switch logic to set RawString;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(RawString))
    {
        @Html.Raw(RawString);
    }
}
```

The result like this:

[image]

Besides, you could also check the RawString, it should an HtmlString, more detail information about using Html.Raw() method, please check [IHtmlHelper.Raw Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper.raw?view=aspnetcore-5.0).